# Error in MockMvc test case for controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I have written a jUnit test case for controller layer method, and it is failing due to mismatch in expected outcome.
Test case is as follows:

```
 @Test
    public void testGetNodeStatusCount() throws Exception {

        ListNodes listNodes = new ListNodes();
       // ArgumentCaptor<Integer> userId = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
        when(userManagementHelper.getNodeStatusCount(0)).thenReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<ListNodes>(listNodes, new HttpHeaders(),
                HttpStatus.OK));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/usermgmt/nodestatus")).andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

Method for which this test case is written is as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/nodestatus", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ListNodes> getNodeStatusCount(@RequestParam("userId") int userId) {
        return userManagementHepler.getNodeStatusCount(userId);
    }
```

Failure message is :
[image]

Thing that I am not getting is that if **status** has been set **OK** than how I am getting 400 in place of 200.

One more thing I am new to this MockMVC testing for "Controller", so please suggest me a source to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller expects a required request parameter, which is why you get status 400 (Bad Request)

You can modify your test to include this request parameter
`mockMvc.perform(get("/usermgmt/nodestatus?userId=0")).andExpect(status().isOk());`

or you can make the request parameter optional
`@RequestParam(value = "userId", required = false, defaultValue = "0")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please suggest me a source to learn all this

Comment: Apologies, I purposefully didn't add any links as these can change over time . Your approach is correct, and if you google "mockMvc tutorials" you will find a lot of link. The only slightly tricky thing in mockMvc is asynchronous testing, bust since your controllers are not async, you should be fine